# Anylogic detect that agent stopped on conveyor

Tags: anylogic

is there any easy way to detect that agent stopped on a roller conveyor because there are other agents ahead? I tried to use dynamic variable and conditional event but it is consuming too much performence. I don´t want to go for dynamically checking condition (with cyclic event) because I have some bad experience with it.

Thanks!

Comment: the options you mention are the only ones... theres no functionality to check if an object stopped in a conveyor

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is like you say, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a `LinkedList<YourAgentType> agentsOnConveyor`.

Whenever an agent enters the conveyor, call `agentsOnConveyor.addLast(agent)`. When it leaves, call `agentsOnConveyor.removeFirst(agent)`.

Now you have a linked representation of the agents on the conveyor.

Last, you use the "on stopped" field in the conveyor and pass the message "upstream" through the linked list, i.e. use a for-loop from the first to the last entry and send them a msg "conveyor stopped".

You may still need to check if the individual agent is moving itself or has also stopped, but it might put you on a working path

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately "on stopped" field only detects failure of conveyor, not that agent has stopped at it. For this reason I can't run for loop function.

We are using conveyor loop as and conveyed agents are transporter for boxes which never leaves this conveyor. We need to detect when this transporter stops while it is in convey block.

Comment: Fair, didn't know that. Maybe try to observe exiting agents: if they do not exit at the expected rate, you use the idea above to tell everyone that "something is not right".

Comment: I posted seperate answer with some pictures to describe the situation in deeper detail.